# Cakephp 4 : Missing Route after tried static method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have controller called BlogsController with method home.

I have created a simple route in `route.php`

```
<?php 

use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::connect('/', ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'home']);
```

Now in browser for localhost/cake_myapp

I am getting error

```
A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view', 0 => 1, 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.
```

Why it's going for view method ?

I have checked `cake routes`

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view',
>   0 => 1, 'plugin' => NULL, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.

As per the error somewhere you are using view action of `Blogs controller` but you have not defined the `route` for that.

To resolve this create a route for view action of `Blogs Controller` for e.g

```
Router::connect('/blogs/view', ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view']);
```

**OR**

```
Router::connect('/blogs/:action', ['controller' => 'Blogs']);
```

Comment: Tried facing same problem.

Comment: @NiloyRony can you please share the code where you are using "view" action?

Comment: In view action just exit("Hello"); else nothing.

Comment: If I use
Router::connect('/', ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'view']); it's working fine. But I want to use here home action not for view action, it also working for index,edit but not working for home.

Comment: @NiloyRony I means the code of anchor tag where you are linking "view" action

Comment: I have created in config/route.php not using any anchor tag.

Comment: @NiloyRony Can you please share your complete error stacktrace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208229/discussion-between-sehdev-and-niloy-rony).